# Windows 10 Universal Power BI App - Open in Command Line/VBS

Tags: command-line, vbscript, powerbi

So I'm just looking for an assist here, I've tried this like 30 different ways, and I cannot figure out what the "Power BI" App (from the Microsoft Webstore) is called in command line.

In Windows 8+, it's possible to open up the "Apps" from command line or VBS using the call: `start ms-clock:` to open the clock app. More info on this [here.](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-8/opening-windows-8-apps-command-prompt-or-script)

Now I'm just trying to open the MSFT Power BI App, from the webstore, in the same fashion, but I cannot figure out what the Power BI call sign is, if anyone could help with this it would be greatly appreciated.

So far, I've tried:

```
start Microsoft-Power-BI:
start Microsoft-Power:
start Power-BI:
start Powerbi:
start Powerbi-cli:
start pbi:
start ms-pbi:
```

I just need some help from someone who would know what the naming syntax would potentially be for an app with spaces in the name. Much thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Love how when you wait 20 more minutes you find your solution.

This post accurately describes the process, it requires full admin rights to your machine/account past that you are good to go.

[Link to Solution](https://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/57000-method-open-any-windows-10-apps-command-line.html)